# RuntimeBinderException when parsing json with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: .net, json, windows-phone, json.net

I'm trying to parse simple json to dynamic object in Windows phone 8. I'm using Newtonsoft.JSON library with this code:

```
dynamic response = JObject.Parse(responseText);
string streamRequestUrl = response._links.streams;
```

I can that _links are present there
[image]
But when I try to read it I get `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException`. How to get _links property value out of it?

Comment: Have you tried it without the debugger enabled? I have a similar issue, works at first after creating the solution, then stops working after a while, if I copy to a new solution it works again. If I run it without the debugger it always works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487305/runtimebinderexception-while-using-newtonsoft-json-with-dynamic-after-installing

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting something similar in VS 2015. The approach using [] to access the properties works, however if I enable "Just My Code" in Tools > Options > Debugging > General. I was able to use the properties on the dynamic objects as normal e.g. code like: `response._links.streams;` worked.

See this other post with a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487305/runtimebinderexception-while-using-newtonsoft-json-with-dynamic-after-installing/33429521#33429521)

Answer (score 0):

The value that you're seeing is the ToString() value. What you're looking for is:

```
response["_links"]
```

For a full example see: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are not alone, I also faced similar issue ( without hangover ;P )

I just modified the file for a space or line and rebuild the entire solution, started working fine in debug mode also...

Happy Holidays!