# Reading JSON data throws runtime exception

Tags: c#, json.net

According to [NewtonSoft's documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm), this code:

```
string props = "{\"lot\":\"TEST\",\"mhd\":\"2016-06-17\"}";
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(props);
string s = json.mhd;
```

should work, but I get a `RunTimeBinderException` when I try it. I have `Micrsoft.CSharp` referenced and the compile works (it is a runtime error). I am compiling against .NET 4.0, using NewtonSoft version 7.

I tried accessing as `json["mhd"]`, which works fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Exception is raised at the deserialisation or at the access of mhd ?
And the json is not of the same shape as in the sample. "[" "]" is missing and the date format could be not deserializable.

Comment: In the latest version of NewtonSoft.Json it deserializes without a problem.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois it throws on `string s = json.mhd`.

Comment: The json object is a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`

Comment: using your code I recreated a console app and it worked.  I did however find this post that might potentially be the solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487305/runtimebinderexception-while-using-newtonsoft-json-with-dynamic-after-installing/33429521#33429521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this case in Newtonsoft.Json 3.5.8 version ,I get this error.
When I upgrade Newtonsoft.Json  package version to 4.5.1 it works . 
I think it has bug on older version.

Answer (score 2):

The `json` object is a JObject, so to get the value you need do:

```
string s = (string)json["mhd"];
```

Answer (score 0):

@Candide pointed out what was wrong with your example, but if you still want to use `json.mhd` syntax and have real *dynamic* object to work with you can do it.

Try to deserialize it using the `ExpandoObjectConverter`:

```
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(props, converter);
```